# How do I run react and express with a single server.js file listening to a single port for production?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

my project consists of a react frontend and an express backend. It has the following hierarchy:

project\

- package.json
- server.js
- node_modules\
- client\

  - package.json
  - src\
  - public\
  - node_modules\

The client folder contains react app which runs on port 3000. The `server.js` in the root directory runs at port 5000.

Currently, to run the app, I used `concurrently` in the root folder, and I added the property `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000/"` into the package.json of the client file. And to start the project I just open port 3000 of the localhost. Any requests I make in the react app is then proxied to `server.js`.

The question:

- When developing for production, is this an ideal approach?
- If not, is there another way of combining react+express into a single server listening through a single port?

Answer (score 2):

You need to build out your `react-app` then point your `Express` server to use static file that get output when build is completed.

Use `npm build` to build out ur project then in Express app use `app.use(express.static(PATH))`

This way when you will run your Express backend you can use your react application on same `port 5000`

Answer (score 0):

Answer by Shivam Sood is absolutely spot on but I thought I would write a more detailed answer as I struggled with this too.

Your folder structure is absolutely fine and many projects use this similar approach even on production. But I will walk you through the process.

1. Firstly, `cd client` into the react folder and run `npm run build`. This will build your react app for production environment.
2. Go inside your project folder and open the `server.js` file and add the following lines.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,"client", "build")));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "build","client", "index.html"));
});
```

This will point your browser to the `index.html` generated by React in the client folder.

3. Now start the server.js by `node server.js` and point your browser to `localhost:PORTINBROWSER` and test.

Your application and the server will listen on the same ports.